# How to apply border image only on one side while still having borders on other sides?

Tags: css, border, border-image

I am using border sizes to make a triangle. I need to add a border-image to one of the borders (I'm going to use a linear-gradient) while keeping the border widths of the other sides so it stays a triangle.

I've tried adding a border-image but it gets applied to all sides.

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 140px;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #1ba5ec;
}
```

I would expect this to show a blue triangle facing right and be able to apply a linear gradient to the border-left

Comment: can you share the visual you need to achieve?